# find similar row index in 2 dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is my test dataset :

```
test
        date app count
1 21-10-18   A     2
2 21-10-19   A     3
3 21-10-23   A     5
4 21-10-19   B     2
5 21-10-24   B     3
```

I would like to group the data based on app column and replace the latest date by `sys.Date` in the date column.
I could get the latest date per app by :

```
latest_date <- test %>% group_by(app)%>%slice(n())

latest_date 
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   app [2]
  date       app   count
  <date>     <chr> <int>
1 21-10-23 A         5
2 21-10-24 B         3
```

How could I find the row indexes in `test` dataset which are match with the rows in `latest_date` ? `(which (test == latest_date)) ????`

what I need at the end is :

```
        date app count
1 21-10-18   A     2
2 21-10-19   A     3
3 21-12-13   A     5
4 21-10-19   B     2
5 21-12-13   B     3
```

Also how one could add the rows here with current date, after the `max.date`
of each group, which the output looks :

```
           date app count
    1 21-10-18   A     2
    2 21-10-19   A     3
    3 21-10-23   A     5
    4 21-12-13   A     5
    5 21-10-19   B     2
    6 21-10-24   B     3
    7 21-12-13   B     3
```

the `add_row` command from `dplyr` does not work on grouped data frame !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace` after doing a group by 'app'

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
test %>% 
   mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
   group_by(app) %>% 
   mutate(date = replace(date, which.max(date), Sys.Date())) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  date       app   count
  <date>     <chr> <int>
1 2021-10-18 A         2
2 2021-10-19 A         3
3 2021-12-13 A         5
4 2021-10-19 B         2
5 2021-12-13 B         3
```

---

With the updated post - use `add_row` with `group_modify`

```
library(tidyr)
test %>%
   mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
   group_by(app) %>% 
   group_modify(~ add_row(.x, date = Sys.Date())) %>%
   fill(count) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
  app   date       count
  <chr> <date>     <int>
1 A     2021-10-18     2
2 A     2021-10-19     3
3 A     2021-10-23     5
4 A     2021-12-13     5
5 B     2021-10-19     2
6 B     2021-10-24     3
7 B     2021-12-13     3
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(date = c("21-10-18", "21-10-19", "21-10-23", "21-10-19", 
"21-10-24"), app = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), count = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  hat if I would like to insert new row as I explained in the question ?

Comment: @user9112767 I checked your expected output, which doesn't seem to have more rows

Comment: @user9112767 Instead of replaceing, do you want to add a new row?

Comment: correct as it is in the question now

Comment: that is perfect, thanks man :)